Why does the Curry paradox require a separate solution in dialetheism?
On the Dialetheism entry on SEP, it is stated that, although dialetheism can offer a solution to the Liar Paradox (by accepting the Liar sentence as a true dialetheia), dialetheists need a separate treatment for the Curry paradox. However, one could see a relation between Curry and Liar as follows.
The Liar has form:

L: ~L.

Where the tilde is the logical negation. Curry has form:

C: C -> P.

Where -> is an implication and P is an arbitrary proposition (including, possibly, ⊥). Let us rewrite L (resp. C) in the following logically equivalent form:

L: (~L) or ⊥.


C: (~C) or P.

Then, it is clear that Liar is a particular case of Curry where P = ⊥. Now, a dialetheist way of dealing with Liar is to accept L as both true and false. Let us now look at the following derivation for Curry:

By LEM, either C or ~C holds.


Assume C. Then, by definition of C, we have (~C) or P. The first disjunct is false; therefore, the second disjunct must hold. Hence P.


Next, assume ~C. This implies (~C) or P. But this is the definition C, hence C holds. Contradiction. Hence P.


In both cases, P holds.

It seems to me that, here, we are using the fact that both C and ~C cannot hold together. However, if we assume that (in a dialetheist way) that C and ~C can hold together without rendering our theory trivial, we get:

By LEM, either C or ~C holds.


Assume C. Then, by definition of C, we have (~C) or P. Now, we can have either ~C or P.


Next, assume ~C. This implies (~C) or P. But this is the definition C, hence C holds. Hence, ~C or P.

In other words, by accepting the contradiction we cannot prove P via Curry.
In short, my question is:
Why is dialetheism enough to deal with Liar, but not with Curry, given my conceptualization of the two paradoxes?

Simplifying the material conditional into a disjunction is a classical logic move. You can't do it in arbitrary logics, because it might not properly capture the essence of the material conditional, if that logic does not allow the same rules of inference as classical logic (and in particular, if it does not allow disjunctive syllogism, which is commonly banned by paraconsistent logics).
What is the essence of the material conditional? If we have P → Q, and we have P, then we should be able to conclude Q (modus ponens). There are a few logics which break this rule, most of them involving defeasible reasoning, but most logics take this to be the defining property of the material conditional, and go out of their way to ensure it remains valid, no matter what happens to disjunction and negation.
So let's look at this again:

We define P: P → Q, and ignore the issue of self-reference for the sake of argument.
If we do not have LEM, then there's the option of declaring P neither true nor false. This is a valid resolution to the paradox, but it is probably unsatisfying under dialetheism, which usually does include LEM.
If LEM is in play, then P may be true. If P is true, then we can immediately expand it into P → Q, and then use the above rule of inference to conclude Q. Dialetheism can't reasonably object to this case of the argument.
Alternatively, P may be false. Under classical logic, this immediately allows us to arrive at P → Q, because a false statement implies "everything." Since P → Q is P, that is a contradiction, so classical logic takes this as proof-by-contradiction that P is true. This gives us at least two obvious points of departure from classical logic - firstly, we may decide that you can't infer P → Q from ~P (which makes sense, because that's the syntactic equivalent of the principle of explosion). Secondly, we may decide that you can't reject the case just because it leads to P ∧ ~P (which makes sense, because dialetheism says that contradictions are not "problems" to be rejected) - but that's not actually a solution, because if we have P ∧ ~P, then we have P, and that puts us back in the P case again.

So, if you want a logic that allows the self reference in Curry's paradox and doesn't devolve into trivialism, you need it to conclude that the implication is false, and you need it to avoid concluding that this makes the implication true. That suggests some kind of relevance logic, although I suspect that other paraconsistent logics are also up to the task.

Why is dialetheism enough to deal with Liar, but not with Curry, given my conceptualization of the two paradoxes?

Dialetheism, by itself, is not a formal logical system. It is simply a general principle that statements may be both true and false simultaneously. It does not describe how the material conditional should work, so a paradox that contains the material conditional may not be possible to properly address without defining how your logic interprets the conditional.
By contrast, the Liar is simply P: ~P. Any logic that allows P ∧ ~P necessarily resolves the Liar, and it is obvious that any logic implementing dialetheism must necessarily allow P ∧ ~P.
